# Exported image to Google Drive geometry is completely black

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

The exported geometry is completely black, actually I need the geometry map to be exported as displayed. Used Google Earth Pro to open the file.

[image]

```
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[58.16719372931096, 23.671386163721188],
          [58.16719372931096, 23.50777699532095],
          [58.53523572149846, 23.50777699532095],
          [58.53523572149846, 23.671386163721188]]], null, false);
          

var L5_collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUD_COVER", 0.1)); //this new command removes cloudy images

print(L5_collection);

var L5_bands = ["B3", "B2", "B1"];

var L5_mosaic = L5_collection.median().clip(geometry).select(L5_bands);

var L5_display = {bands: L5_bands, min: 0, max: 0.5};

Map.addLayer(L5_mosaic, L5_display, "Landsat-5");

Map.centerObject(geometry);

Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: L5_mosaic,
  description: 'Landsat-5',
  scale: 30, 
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
  region: geometry 
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am getting the exported image as black, where i should get the map

Answer (score 0):

I think the link below answers your question. You may need to download QGIS if you don't already have it (it's free and relatively easy to use). Otherwise I don't think you can directly import a tif file generated in GEE into Google Earth Pro.

[.tif image (made in QGIS 3) imported into Google Earth Pro is blank/has no symbology options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323219/tif-image-made-in-qgis-3-imported-into-google-earth-pro-is-blank-has-no-symbo/323353)